# setMapTypeId changes a scale of the map. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Code that by some unexpected reason changes scale:
`map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);`

Map is set with code:

```
    try {
        var lat = (app.problem.latitude) ? app.problem.latitude : -27.479624,
            lon = (app.problem.longitude) ? app.problem.longitude : 153.033654,
            coords = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

        // map options
        var options = {
                center: coords,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                  style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                   position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
                },
                // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                zoom: 18
            };


        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.el, options);

        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                position: coords, 
                draggable: false, 
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, 
            });

        this.marker.setMap(this.map);
        // this.map.setCenter(coords);
    } catch(e){
        console.error('location problem:', e.message);
    }
```

Comment: It could be that *the highest zoom level at which satellite imagery is available for a given location* is less than you expect. Check `MaxZoomService()`

Comment: What exactly happens? Does the zoom change? If it does, can you still zoom using mousewheel/zoom button?

Comment: it may be the max zoom for `TERRAIN`, but it seems that i can zoom `SATELLITE` and `ROADMAP` to the previous level...

Comment: thanks, guys! that is `TERRAIN` who had different maximum zoom value